# See an object's height in pixels within your browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I would like to know how many pixels a textbox, which contains 4 lines of text, is high. Is there any way to see the dimensions of an object while you are on a website?

Comment: Right-click -> inspect element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `firebug` plugin in firefox or `chrome inspector` on chrome:

press `F12` on chrome to load th Inspector.

download the firebug plugin from http://getfirebug.com/

In chrome when you inspect an element, the dimentions are in the right pane -> metrics.

In firebug this is done the same but the name is box model

Answer (score 1):

Firefox with the firebug plugin is probably the best browser for developers (my opinion). If can tell you the calculated dimensions for elements including their padding and margins.